# Problem with commit history in Bitbucket using Git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am facing issue to get back my previous commits, as soon as I used --f to push it shows just that commit where I used --f and earsed the previous ones. is there any way or any how to get back my commits history?

when I get back to link of the previous commit it shows this msg:

"This commit is unreachable from any branch or tag in this repository. It may be from a fork outside of this repository.

"

the code I used to push :
git push -f origin master

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
git reset --hard <commithash you need>
```

to restore your desired commit (you will need the hash obviously).

If you lost the desired commit hash you may be able to recover it using

```
git reflog
```

Make sure to backup your current work on a separate branch in case you make any mistake.

This might help you:
https://www.jvt.me/posts/2021/10/23/undo-force-push/

Comment: I tried this 'git reset --hard <commithash you need>

got this error "fatal: ambiguous argument 'e1b2805': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
"

Comment: Seems like your hash is wrong.
Use git reflog to identify the correct hash.

Comment: Should I inculde the full hash or just the 7 digits ?

Comment: 7 digits should work fine

Comment: I have done "git reflog" it just shows the latest commit hash which caused the issue, I am trying to get back the old commits which i have lost

Comment: You should use reflog on your remote branch due to the fact that you pushed to origin
git reflog refs/remotes/origin/<yourbranchnamehere>

Comment: it just shows this 8b1b629 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) refs/remotes/origin/master@{0}: update by push

Comment: I just tried the process myself, created some commits, resetted the head with git reset --soft HEAD~1 to a previous commit, force pushed with git push -f origin master and resetting using git reset --hard <commithash you need>. This worked a treat. Please provide more information in regards of what exactly you did before your force push.

Comment: @SlamRsps: if you can't use the short hash ID, this means *you do not have that commit in your Git repository*. That means you cannot use *your* Git repository to get that commit back. You must find some repository that *does* have the commit: clone that one, or `git fetch` from it, to get the commit back.